# I have an external page I want to print the value of

Tags: php, variables, curl

I have an external page I want to print the value of 
I'm working on a personal server appserv 
I used curl of the site :http://login.live.com/login.srf?id=2&svc=mail&cbid=1&msppjph=1&tw=0&fs=1&fsa=1&fsat=1296000&lc=1033&_lang=EN
All I want is to print this variable name = PPFT

`<input type="hidden" name="PPFT" id="i0327" value="CjS9*L3LVhU9sc!dH70OyGoJKKDPgDxqPN!rP6c0IGpw9mq8clZJccbv0B!USsIsjYmrf6nuuW2jzf*yvMlReHpT7zR5unDipkBJ!*bbgW4Ibm5I!SOCeglUJ4iLO85N2WIQ!G37lhXRKQ0t3txFwmE$"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://login.live.com/login.srf?id=2&svc=mail&cbid=1&msppjph=1&tw=0&fs=1&fsa=1&fsat=1296000&lc=1033&_lang=EN');
$doc = new DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$value = $xpath->query("//input[@name='PPFT']")->item(0)->getAttribute('value');

echo $value;
```

This will get the value set for the `PPFT` form field for you. Make sure you have `allow_url_fopen` enabled in your `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `file_get_contents(URL)` where `URL=the external site` and set that equal to a variable which you can echo in value.